# Edit form in desginer that is generated at load time

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Hi
Just inherited a VB forms application that must be modified. My problem is that the controls are placed at the form at the load event. There is no controls on the form when I open the form1.vb in Solution explorer.
How can I achieve changing the design for the form?

/Andy.l

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to locate the code that creates and adds controls (I guess you found it in the Load event) and modify that code.  Or else comment that code out and add all the same controls in the designer.

If the controls are not dynamic (i.e. if the Load event always adds the same controls in the same positions), then your best long-term solution is my second suggestion (add all the controls "properly" in the designer).